# Unable to click a button using autoit

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, autoit

[image]

While trying to identify the Logon buttons Class and Instance using the autoit finder tool, it returns the same class and Advanced Mode, Name, ID, Text, for the Help, Logon and Cancel.

Only thing that differs is Position, and the visible texts.

And also i cannot use mouse click based on the position.

So, ControlClick Coords also doesn't work. Is there any way that i can click on the Logon button?

Note: I have also tried with the Autoit recorder, and that too dint work

Comment: can u share the html?

Comment: @noor This is a windows dialog, thats why i came for autoit.

Comment: have u tried using robot by clicking on that position...actually to work on it, u have to give us some information....like html, csspath or xpath ....if no information is available, than it will be tough to give solution

Comment: @noor This is a windows dialog, so there will be no xpath css html available, you would be aware. And its totally relates to autoit. AutoIt related queries please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

1. You mentioned that you can't click on the position. I don't know why this sholdn't work, but you can get the Windowposition with [WinGetPos()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinGetPos.htm) and calculate the position of the button and klick it with MouseClick().
2. Why don't you use button commands. Enter text to the first box by using Send() and then give buttoncommands like TAB and ENTER like this:

`Send("Login[TAB]PW[TAB][TAB][TAB][ENTER]")`

Hope something works for you!